# Unable to Update the progress bar inside and alert dialog builder

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, progress-bar, progressdialog

I am trying to create a progress bar inside a alert dialog builder and trying to update the progress when i click on button using threads and handlers .....but every time i click on the start button it crashes ....

```
package com.example.progressbar_thread;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button Start;
int i = 0;
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
ProgressBar myProgressBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
    Start.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Alert dialog builder section 
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myDialogBuilder.setTitle("Progress...");
    View ProgressView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progressbar,
            null);
    myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);   

    myDialogBuilder.setView(ProgressView);
    myDialogBuilder.create().show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (i < myProgressBar.getMax()) {

                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myProgressBar.setProgress(i);   //Updading progress 

                    }

                });

                i++;

            }

        }
    }).start();

    }

    }enter code here
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from LogCat, right now it's impossible to know why it actually crashes without fine-reading your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change your code little bit....

you have to change the following lines

```
 View ProgressView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progressbar,
        null);
myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);   

myDialogBuilder.setView(ProgressView);
myDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

to----

```
 View ProgressView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progressbar,
        null);
myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)ProgressView.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);   

myDialogBuilder.setView(myProgressBar);
myDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

I hope it will help you.....